# Multiple Custom_Background, is it possible?

Tags: theme-development, options, custom-background

Is it possible to create multiple "custom background" administration pages? A site I'm doing now needs 2 different background in 2 different areas, I would really love giving my client the same experience for both backgrounds in terms of colour/image/select-repeat etc.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Amit:**

The answer is *"Yes, it is possible."* The follow up question is *"Do you really want to?"*

I thought it would be fun to see if I could build a plugin to do what you are asking for so I decided to see if it was possible. Of course I was able to make it work but I fear that the plugin code I wrote needs to be so tightly coupled with the existing code in WordPress that it might easily break on a core update.

This code handles all the admin console side of things by creating a new menu item in the *Appearance* section called *"Special Background."* What it does not do is provide any way to actually use the background; that's phase two of the plugin and will require hooking many of the functions in `/wp-includes/themes.php` and frankly I don't know if I'll get a chance to write that code.

The reason I stopped without doing it is I didn't know the requirements for where the special background should show and where the regular one would show. I assume maybe for selected pages and/or URL paths?

Nonetheless, here if the code for the plugin (which you can also download from [gist](http://gist.github.com/554874)):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Special Background
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/972/
Description: Example to show how to add a special background using exiting background admin page in core.
Version: 0.1
Author: Mike Schinkel
Author URI: http://mikeschinkel.com/custom-wordpress-plugins/
*/
add_filter('admin_menu','add_special_background_menu_item');
function add_special_background_menu_item() {
    add_theme_page(__('Special Background'), __('Special Background'),'edit_theme_options','special-background','special_background_admin_page');
}
add_filter('admin_init','add_js_for_special_background');
function add_js_for_special_background() {
    global $custom_background;
    if (is_special_background_page()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-background');
        wp_enqueue_style('farbtastic');
    }
    $hook = 'load-appearance_page_special-background';
    add_action($hook, array(&$custom_background, 'admin_load'));
    add_action($hook, array(&$custom_background, 'take_action'), 49);
    add_action($hook, array(&$custom_background, 'handle_upload'), 49);    
}
add_filter('theme_mod_background_image',      'theme_mod_special_background_image');
add_filter('theme_mod_background_image_thumb','theme_mod_special_background_image_thumb');
add_filter('theme_mod_background_repeat',     'theme_mod_special_background_repeat');
add_filter('theme_mod_background_position_x', 'theme_mod_special_background_position_x');
add_filter('theme_mod_background_attachment', 'theme_mod_special_background_attachment');
add_filter('theme_mod_background_color',      'theme_mod_special_background_color');
function theme_mod_special_background_image($defaults) {
    return theme_mod_special_background_image_attrs('image',$defaults);
}
function theme_mod_special_background_image_thumb($defaults) {
    return theme_mod_special_background_image_attrs('image_thumb',$defaults);
}
function theme_mod_special_background_repeat($defaults) {
    return theme_mod_special_background_image_attrs('repeat',$defaults);
}
function theme_mod_special_background_position_x($defaults) {
    return theme_mod_special_background_image_attrs('position_x',$defaults);
}
function theme_mod_special_background_attachment($defaults) {
    return theme_mod_special_background_image_attrs('attachment',$defaults);
}
function theme_mod_special_background_color($defaults) {
    return theme_mod_special_background_image_attrs('color',$defaults);
}
function theme_mod_special_background_image_attrs($attr,$defaults) {
    if (is_special_background_page()) {
        $mods = get_option( 'mods_' . get_current_theme() );
        $defaults = (!empty($mods["special_background_{$attr}"]) ? $mods["special_background_{$attr}"] : '');
    }
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('pre_update_option_mods_' . get_current_theme(),'pre_update_option_special_background_image',10,2);
function pre_update_option_special_background_image($newvalue, $oldvalue) {
    static $times_called = 0;
    if (!empty($_POST) && is_special_background_page()) {
        if ((isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='save') || isset($_POST['reset-background']) || isset($_POST['remove-background'])) {
            switch ($times_called) {
                case 0:
                    $newvalue = special_background_image_value_swap('image',$newvalue,$oldvalue);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $newvalue = special_background_image_value_swap('image_thumb',$newvalue,$oldvalue);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            if ($times_called==0 && isset($_POST['background-repeat'])) {
                $newvalue = special_background_image_value_swap('repeat',$newvalue,$oldvalue);
            }
            if ($times_called==1 && isset($_POST['background-position-x'])) {
                $newvalue = special_background_image_value_swap('position_x',$newvalue,$oldvalue);
            }
            if ($times_called==2 && isset($_POST['background-attachment'])) {
                $newvalue = special_background_image_value_swap('attachment',$newvalue,$oldvalue);
            }
            if ($times_called==3 && isset($_POST['background-color'])) {
            $newvalue = special_background_image_value_swap('color',$newvalue,$oldvalue);
      }
    }
    $times_called++;
  }
  return $newvalue;
}
function special_background_image_value_swap($swap_what,$newvalue,$oldvalue) {
  $newvalue["special_background_{$swap_what}"] = $newvalue["background_{$swap_what}"];
  $newvalue["background_{$swap_what}"] = $oldvalue["background_{$swap_what}"];
  return $newvalue;
}
function special_background_admin_page() {
  global $custom_background;
  if (is_special_background_page()) {
    global $parent_file,$submenu_file,$title;
    $parent_file = 'themes.php';
    $submenu_file = 'themes.php?page=special-background';
    $title = 'Special Background';
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php');
    ob_start();
    $custom_background->admin_page();
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $html = preg_replace('#<h2>([^<]+)</h2>#','<h2>Special Background</h2>',$html);
    echo $html;
    include(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php');
    exit;
  }
}
function is_special_background_page() {
  global $pagenow;
  return ($pagenow=='themes.php' &&
         isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']== 'special-background');
}
```

Frankly it is too much code to explain proactively but I'll be happy to answer specific questions.

Comment: Tip: `list($var1, $var2) = array($var2, $var1); // swaps the values of $var1 and $var2`

Comment: That's a plugin I would definitely wrap up in a class.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: Can you add a little description on your swap/save concept? Are normally those theme_mod_background_image theme modification values used by wp core to offer the standard header? What do you do if there is no header in theme? I'm thinking about creating some hook/option facade object in my fork... updated: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Modification_API .

Comment: I forked you. http://gist.github.com/554944

Comment: @hakre; thanks for the tip on the swap. I am familiar with it though. You must understand that when I first wrote the function it was much more complicated and I refactored it down to what it is so I wasn't originally thinking it would be as simplistic. I also don't tend to wrap things up in a class for here on StackExchange because it make it harder for people to understand when all the class plumbing is in place (yet, it is not optimal; if I use a class more people will be scared off it; if I don't use a class I'm teaching them less good practice.)

Comment: @hakre - WordPress stores the header in an option called `mods_{$theme}`; my theme was called wp30 so it is `mods_wp30`. It has a background image, image thumb and color. I just intercept update and add my differently named elements for the special background, hence the swap, and then I do the reverse upon getting the option. WordPress doesn't give context in `set_theme_mod()` which made this much more difficult than it should have been (I requested a filter, maybe you could support it? http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14721)

Comment: @hakre - I had to use the order of saving to figure out what was being saved which is very scary because of how brittle it is; they add one thing to `/wp-includes/custom-background.php` and it all breaks! As for git, I don't know it and am not ready to learn it. I understand forking is a good thing in git but I always view forking as a bad thing. Are you wanting to collaborate on this for the repository at WordPress.org?  If so it needs to handle multiple backgrounds, not just one.

Comment: @hakre - I just looked at your fork. It's "clean" code but it is so abstracted that it's hard to follow. I used to code that way and used to (literally) preach that coding style in my training courses for corporate, government and military programmers. But since working with WordPress I've come to appreciate that the less abstract coding can actually be a benefit at times because it is so much easier to understand. FWIW.

Comment: oh not that abstract. I only like to have the hooks hooking into the same names. and to setup the variants in the beginning of the class. I run in some mess while refactoring your base, so these three classes appeared which might look a bit oversized. the last one is coupled to the first one, the routine can be merged into the plugin class but I have not done that yet. The other class was something I'd liked to play with to overcome your add_filter / bunch of global functions -> one global function. so that was abstract :D. :P Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: I'm starting with git as well. I have no problems with forking, I think it's like having a new repository. From what I've heard that works good with git, so let's fork around a bit. This gist is a very nice pasteboard. You can see where you got stuff from etc. That's cool. --- I dunno if it makes sense to add more than one background image in WP. Maybe? But I think the problem is that it's not designed that way in core, there must have been added some number or key to differ between each of the backgrounds. Probably it's simpler to just re-code that form and offer admin pages.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: Try before you buy :D : http://progit.org/book/

Comment: @hakre: Abstract is relative. You want to see abstract? Read my one book on programming! http://mikeschinkel.com/books/ I do like Gist but not planning to work with Git, at least not unless/until WordPress adopts it (which I think is unlikely.) Yes, it would make a lot of sense to have multiple backgrounds; envision an online magazine with 5 sections; one background for each plus the home page. And whenever possible I try to work with what WordPress has, asking for hooks where I need them, rather than throw out and start over. That's just my philosophy for extending WordPress.

Comment: wow! that works amazing! I'm speechless.

Comment: @Amit: Speechless, but you can still type eh? :-)  Glad I could help. I'm burned out on this one, I spent a lot more time on it than I expected when I started to answer, but if you client needs those backgrounds to display created I do offer consulting by the hour... :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically **it's possible** (so to extend the wordpress source), but not by default. So I would give the answer to no. The build-in background theme feature is for a single graphics only be default.

But if you describe a little bit more about the "2 different areas" you're writing about, there might be something nice to suggest next to this.

Edit: Highlight for MikeSchinkel. Plugins are extending the wordpress source.

Comment: Well.. There's the main site (20 sections or so) and then there's like a sub-site under one those sections which changes for this special event and need its own style colours and background image.

Theoretically I could tell the client to upload an image to the "master page" of each section and call it "some-how" but I like the custom background functionality and semantic position in the CMS.

Comment: are you using a template per section? that might be something to hook in. Or to override with a subtheme for a certain area (that would scale to two background images then in total because you would have two themes, parent and child theme).

Comment: Ye of little faith! You should know not to say something is not possible with WordPress! ;-)

Comment: I didn't. I mean it's a pile of PHP you only need to re-arrange a little to get things done :)

Comment: True. But you shouldn't discourage people; where there is a will there is a way!