# Remove title attribute from images

Tags: images, hooks, filters, post-thumbnails

I'm looking for a way to remove the *title* attribute from images, preferably through using a hook or a filter.

Most clients don't bother giving images a proper title, thus eliminating the purpose of this attribute. I prefer no tooltips to random, non-descriptive ones.

Comment: Yeah I get asked this a lot, even though its not best practice, some clients don't care. I use the JavaScript method below, incase they change their minds later. (+1 for it being a valid question, even if its not the best idea...)

Answer (score 9):

I would *strongly* discourage this.  A better, more sustainable practice would be to educate your clients on the value of the `title` attribute and teach them how to use it properly.

Simply removing it is putting a bandage on the symptom, *not* combating the disease.

However, if you do want to remove the attribute anyway, there are a couple of ways to do it:

## Use a Content Filter

Post content runs through a filter before being displayed on the screen.  This filter will do several things: transform quote marks into curly quotes, capitalize the P in WordPress, etc.  It also handles shortcodes that are present in the content.

You can pass your content through a filter that uses regular expressions to find `<img />` tags and remove the `title` attribute.

## Use a Plug-in

A quick search of the plug-in repository returned [Img Title Removal](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/img-title-removal/), a plug-in that claims to do exactly what you want.  A quick look at the code shows it does option 1 exactly:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Img Title Removal
Plugin URI: http://www.glauserconsulting.com/2008/11/nu-agency/
Description: Filter plugin that removes all title tags from images in posts.
Author: Ivan Glauser
Version: 0.2.1
Author URI: http://www.glauserconsulting.com
*/

add_filter('the_content', 'remove_img_titles');

function remove_img_titles($text) {

    // Get all title="..." tags from the html.
    $result = array();
    preg_match_all('|title="[^"]*"|U', $text, $result);

    // Replace all occurances with an empty string.
    foreach($result[0] as $img_tag) {
        $text = str_replace($img_tag, '', $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
?>
```

## Use JavaScript

A third option would be to dynamically remove the `title` attributes after they've been rendered on the page.  If you absolutely *must* remove them, this is the system I'd recommend because the `title` will still be in the HTML code (for screen readers) but will be removed when the document loads so you avoid the "random, non-descriptive" tooltips.

Using jQuery, you can select all `<img />` elements on the page that have a `title` attribute and remove it.  Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('img[title]').each(function() { $(this).removeAttr('title'); });
});
```

Comment: Screen readers use the `alt` attribute. The `title` attribute is should never be an instrument of accessibility.

Comment: The plugin is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This got flagged for moderator attention with essentialy same sentiment as toscho above and couple links http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200412/the_alt_and_title_attributes/ http://www.rnib.org.uk/professionals/webaccessibility/wacblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?id=38 maybe worth revising?..

Comment: Odd that I don't see flags on my own things unless I view my own profile ... revised.

Comment: +1 for the JavaScript method. No loss of content for search engines.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a non-js solution without hacking the core, try this in your themes `function.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'remove_image_text' );
function remove_image_text( $attr ) {
    unset( $attr['alt'] );
    unset( $attr['title']) ;
    return $attr;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

If you're looking for a way to let the title `<input>` field empty and not automatically loaded with the file's name on a picture upload, here's a way:

Goto wp-admin/includes/media.php

Line 911 `<input type='text' class='text urlfield' name='attachments[$post->ID][url]' value='" . esc_attr($url) . "' /><br />`

Change it to: `<input type='text' class='text urlfield' name='attachments[$post->ID][url]' value='' /><br />`

I also have lots of clients that dont care about this.

Comment: I would [not change a core file](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/what-are-some-reasons-why-you-should-not-hack-wordpress-core-files), since this will lead to problems when you upgrade WordPress. If possible, it's better to use a hook.

Comment: Yeah not the best ever, how could we do that in a hook?

Comment: I can't say this strongly enough: **don't hack core!!!** ... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/what-are-some-reasons-why-you-should-not-hack-wordpress-core-files

Comment: Agreed **NEVER HACK THE CORE** that is why they allow filters. If the you can not add a filter or action then so be it find a new route. **BUT NEVER HACK THE CORE!!!!**

Comment: Funny how emotional the thread gets. As they said in ancient roman times: "All routes lead towards rom" :)