# Remove all link title attributes

Tags: links, customization, accessibility

After reading [this](https://silktide.com/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/) and [this](https://silktide.com/things-i-learned-by-pretending-to-be-blind-for-a-week/), I want to remove the title attribute from all links of my blog, as that is good from accessibility point of view. How this can be achieved?

**UPDATE**

I found a [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/6137/25187) **how to remove title attribute from images**, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: [The title attribute is fine if used correctly](http://webaim.org/articles/gonewild/#title). Why do you think that removing it is "good"?

Comment: It can be abused and thus breaking the accessibility. That's why it was removed from the default WP TinyMCE editor.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I updated the question.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I know about that solution and it doesn't work for me, I don't know why.

Comment: @s_ha_dum ... and that answers are not accepted yet.

Comment: People often neglect to accept answers but that one looks like it's should work. Are you sure the question isn't missing something relevant?

Comment: What here can be more relevant? Give me an idea and I will improve my question. You can see my blog (android.info.md), all title attributes are there. I already added the mentioned by @denis.stoyanov function to my function.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to preserve the images title attribute? If not here is a code that fixes that for you:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_title_attr');

function remove_title_attr($text) {

    // Get all title="..." tags from the html.
    $result = array();
    preg_match_all('|title="[^"]*"|U', $text, $result);

    // Replace all occurances with an empty string.
    foreach($result[0] as $html_tag) {
        $text = str_replace($html_tag, '', $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
```

[Found it here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/6137/76287). It works on c9.io. I believe it will work in your case, too.

**Edit 1**: This will remove the title attribute from all your posts' content. Do you want to remove it globally from all elements?

Comment: So your answer is a copy/paste of an answer (a much, much better one) by EAMann? Please don't do that but thanks for pointing out the duplicate.

Comment: @denis.stoyanov For now yes, I want to remove it globally from all elements, but I must investigate this more. Thank you!

Comment: @denis.stoyanov I know about this function, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes it is. And I've included a link to his reply (**EAMann**) where he (**Iurie**) can find more detailed information. Is this against the Terms? I'll re-read the forum Terms of Use. I guess that has slipped out from my mind. Sorry for that. Will know in future. Thanks!