# Prevent WordPress from adding image' title automatically

Tags: images, gallery, title

I wrote a plugin that set default title for all non-set (empty) titles and leaves the titles set manually (non-empty).

The problem is when I upload new photos (to gallery), WordPress by default set the title to file's name. How Can I disable it and **force WordPress to use empty string as default image title**?

Comment: checkout this link : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/remove-title-attribute-from-images

Comment: @ErezLieberman isn't it about removing existing titles? I don't want to remove the titles set by administrator. I only want to prevent WordPress from adding default one when you upload the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the following to clear the image attachment's title when it's *inserted* but not *updated*:

```
/**
 * Empty the image attachment's title only when inserted not updated
 */
add_filter( 'wp_insert_attachment_data', function( $data, $postarr )
{
    if( 
        empty( $postarr['ID'] ) 
        && isset( $postarr['post_mime_type'] )
        && wp_match_mime_types( 'image', $postarr['post_mime_type'] ) 
    )
        $data['post_title'] = '';

    return $data;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Here we use the `wp_insert_attachment_data` filter to override the attachment's title  if the attachment's `ID` is empty and the mime type is an *image* type according to [`wp_match_mime_types()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_match_mime_types). A simple `'image' === substr( $postarr['post_mime_type'], 0, 5 )` check might work as well. You could even target a given mime type, like `image/jpeg`.

Comment: *...says the man with the face as white of that of  a ghost* ;-)

Comment: *The Phantom of the WoPera* ;-) @PieterGoosen