# Passing page url into a custom field via the Press-This bookmarklet

Tags: customization, custom-field, urls

Here's my situation. I want to use a modified version of the WordPress **Press This** bookmarklet to pass the current page URL to a custom field on my post. In this case, let's say my custom field is `linked_list_url`.

I'm guessing there are four pieces to this:

- Add a custom input field to the page generated by the bookmarklet
- Grab the URL of the page the bookmarklet was used on and store it
- Pass the stored URL to the custom input field
- Pass the contents of the custom input field to WordPress, setting it as the key for the custom field

I've modified the bookmarklet to have a custom input field and it's pulling the URL off of the page and passing it to the input box, but when I submit the bookmarklet, nothing is passed to WordPress.

Here's my press-this custom bookmarklet: http://pastebin.com/UjNkpNrE

**Specifically:** Once I have the URL passed to the custom input field in the bookmarklet, how should I go about having the contents of that field passed to WordPress into the custom field `linked_list_url`?

Comment: Here's the custom code, excerpted: http://pastebin.com/6xVyLfMm

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/bookmark-this/ re: hooking into `admin_head-post-new.php` and setting a custom field value based on a parameter passed in the query string...

Comment: Are you modifying the core `/wp-admin/press-this.php` file to achieve this? Because [it's not a good idea to change core files](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/what-are-some-reasons-why-you-should-not-hack-wordpress-core-files), you should try to find a hook to do what you want from a plugin file, so you can survive upgrades. I think your first three steps are solved in the `_wp_http_referer` form field, and you can solve step four in the `wp_insert_post` hook.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but I wrote a plugin to take care of this: http://yjsoon.com/dfll-plugin

I'm not sure if your using linked_list_url means you're already using the plugin, but if you are, I just updated it. :)