# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot unset string offsets when trying to upload any file to media library

Tags: wp-admin, core

When trying to upload files to the Wordpress media library I encounter the following error:

> Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page.

I enabled debugging mode in WP by adding

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

to my wordpress config file.

After taking a look at debug.log there seems to be a problem with one of the WP core files `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot unset string offsets`

[The full debug log](https://gist.github.com/victorlane/e80ff2f97563b607687dd32036effacd)

The function throwing the error is `clean_dirsize_cache`

Line 8381: `unset( $directory_cache[ $path ] );`

I've already tried the following:

- Allocated more memory in php.ini
- Changed limit for max file sizes

The error happens on every file I try to upload, file size or file type doesn't seem to matter.

As I'm not experienced with Wordpress and I haven't worked on this site previously at all I'm not quite sure what caused this to start occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue on only one of the three wordpress sites managed by a multisite wordpress.
I am not experienced with Wordpress either, but I have managed to get uploads working by replacing

```
if ( empty( $directory_cache ) ) {
    return;
}
```

by

```
if ( empty( $directory_cache ) || !is_array($directory_cache) ) {
    return;
}
```

at line 8368 in wp-includes/functions.php

I have not yet encountered any inconvenience with this change but it still might have some unexpected implications.

Comment: Note that, if you modify core files, there's a strong possibility your changes will be overwritten in a future update. See [What are some reasons you should not modify core files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/what-are-some-reasons-why-you-should-not-hack-wordpress-core-files) for more information and suggestions.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, as it will simply break again the next time WP updates.