# How can I determine where I want to edit in the backend (server)

Tags: posts, videos

My boss has a wordpress site and he wants me to give him the ability to add videos from a site called vzaar. I see the form, I see the main PHP file for editing posts. Unfortunately I can't track the form down to the backend file. How can I know which file I want to edit. The theme were using is called mercurial. All I need to do is add one select box and probably some backend logic.

My background: I'm really familiar with Ruby on Rails, but have little experience with PHP. Seems simple enough, i'm just not super stoked about having to re-engineer the WP theme.

Comment: WordPress development never involves editing core files, but before you dive into [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org), you could possibly just use [an existing plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vzaar-media-management/).

Answer (score 2):

> My boss has a wordpress site

Ah, so many stories start this way.

You don't, of course, want to edit core WP files; if you do, you will lose the changes when you update, among other issues. [Modifying WordPress core files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files)

Why not use the existing post/page editor and a plugin that will make it easy for him/her?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=vzaar

If you want to keep him/her out of the post/page editor, try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ to add your own meta and text editor boxes.

Comment: This is unfortunate, because I do believe that we are trying to extend the functionality of a plugin, which means the likelihood of being able to find a pre-packaged solution is less likely (i would assume). Will try the solutions, thanks.