# Redirect outside WP after login

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, wp-login-form

I have `http://example.com/admin.php`

There I check whether the user is admin or not. If not, I send the user to the wp-login page like this:

```
blog.mysite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com/admin.php
```

I expect redirect back for admin.php but WordPress always sends me to `wp-admin` control panel.

After researching, I found that when the destination host is not in filter `allowed_redirect_hosts`, WP just redirects the user to `wp-admin`.

How can I add more hosts to the filter?

If I put [this example from the WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/allowed_redirect_hosts) in `functions.php`, it stops working.

```
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts' , 'my_allowed_redirect_hosts' , 10 );
function my_allowed_redirect_hosts($content){
    $content[] = 'blog.example.com';
    $content[] = 'codex.example.com';
    // wrong: $content[] = 'http://codex.example.com';
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: It looks like that should work.  When you say "it stops working", what do you mean?  Users get redirected to `wp-admin`, or you get error messages, or the site goes blank, or...?  Also, if you can post the code you used -- not the stuff from the Codex, but the actual code that you tried in `functions.php` -- that might help.

Comment: I tested the filter and successfully added `www.google.com` to the 'safe' list. That filter works. The problem is elsewhere. Something else in code not posted is going on that is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you two.I added the code just replacing the strings for "google.com", to the functions.php. Just it stop working and the page goes blank, like a php error. Maybe i must add the code in the theme's function.php?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally it works! What I was doing wrong is putting the code in the WP functions.php file, and not in my custom theme functions.php file.

Thanks all!

Comment: Glad you got it working. For future reference:  All code that you are adding belongs in either your theme files (usually `wp-content/[themename]/functions.php`) or a plugin (usually in `wp-content/plugins/[...]`).  The general rule of thumb is [don't hack core](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files/).