# Accessing two databases wordpress

Tags: functions, database, wpdb

I'm trying to access a second database with my wordpress system.  To do this, I've attempted to follow the advice [found here](http://bavotasan.com/2011/access-another-database-in-wordpress/) which seems to have worked for a lot of people.

In summary, I'm adding the following line to my functions.php:

```
global $newdb;
$newdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
$newdb->show_errors();
```

Unfortunately, when I add this I come up with the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'wpdb' not found in /home/mine/www/wp-includes/functions.php

I'm sure I must be missing wrong (obviously, right?) but the instructions don't seem to have any extra steps that I've been leaving out.

Thanks for any help

Comment: did you make it global ? ..... global newdb ?

Comment: @pl4g4 Thanks for the response!  I did, and i'll add that to my description above.... I assume you're making sure that I had "global $newdb" preceding the rest of my $newdb code, right?

Comment: yes, Remember that you have to declare $newdb to be a global variable in the function that you’re going to use it.

Comment: Are your constants (`DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, etc) all `define`d somewhere?  Are you calling `new wpdb()` in a filter or action, or just bare in the `functions.php` file?

Comment: @PatJ  DB_USER and alike have their attributes hard-coded in (I simply used generic terms for interweb privacy purposes).  The calling of new wpdb() is just bare in functions.php.  Might that be an issue?  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: When you say "my functions.php", which file (full path from the WordPress root) are you referring to?  (If you're editing `/wp-includes/functions.php`, please stop immediately.  "Your" functions.php file should be at `/wp-content/themes/{your-theme-name}/functions.php`.)

Comment: @neanderslob the code should be inside a function... use a filter or an action. check my answer and try that, and u must be modifying the /wp-content/themes/{your-theme-name}/functions.php file.

Comment: @pl4g4 actually just tried to use an add_action as per the solution below and it threw back `Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()`.  Any idea as to why that might have happened?  I'm really scratching my head now.

Comment: What file are you editing?  If it's not in the `/wp-content` folder somewhere, [please stop that](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files/). You should not need to edit core files.

Comment: @PatJ  Yea... that's embarrassing I was definitely editing the /wp-includes/functions.php.  Added it to my themes functions.php instead and it worked like a charm.  (Nothing like a good 1D10T error to spice up your day.)  Many thanks; feel free to type the finding up in an answer if you feel so inclined, and I'll mark it as solved.  Thanks again.

Comment: Done.  (It's unfortunate that there are multiple `functions.php` files to choose from, and I can totally understand how you might start editing the wrong one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When enhancing WordPress functionality, always use the theme's `functions.php` file (located, generally, in `{WP root}/wp-content/themes/{your theme}/functions.php`), or [put your code into a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

The rules for [hacking core code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files/) are similar to the rules for optimization.

1. Don't do it.
2. (for experts only) Don't do it yet.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
add_action('init', 'doSomething');
function doSomething(){
     global $newdb;
     $newdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
     $newdb->show_errors();
}
```

Comment: Alright, this is getting weird.  Now it's giving me `Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()`  That shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Comment: that code is working for me. where r u adding the code? ... check what @Pat J said.

Comment: yea..... you were on the right track with that question.  PatJ above rightly chided me for editing my wp-includes file and pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks for trying to help me bumble my way through this though!