# Custom Structure permalinks error 404

Tags: url-rewriting, permalinks

i have changed the wordpress custom structure permalink to `/%post_id%/%postname%/` and get this error :

**404 Not Found
The requested URL /mysite/blog/1/hello-world/ was not found on this server.**

- wordpress version ***3.1.7***
- site address:  **localhost/mysite/blog**

i'v changed this function in **misc.php** and saw the error again!

```
function got_mod_rewrite() {
    //$got_rewrite = apache_mod_loaded('mod_rewrite', true); //old line with false negative;
    $got_rewrite = true;//force the response to true as we know mod_rewite is installed;
    return apply_filters('got_rewrite', $got_rewrite);
}
```

Comment: [You should *never* change core files in WordPress.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files/1572#1572) The line in `misc.php` that you commented out will return TRUE by default, which means that, for some reason, `apache_mod_loaded()` doesn't think that `mod_rewrite` is installed. Double-check your server config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mehdi, it's common problem, as Apache server is not set by this way by default. Your problem can be solved with some very simple steps (simply quoting Samuel B):

> If you want to use permalinks, you will need to make a change inside another file:
>   apache > Conf and find the file `httpd.conf`. Open that in a text editor. Use the search facility in the editor to find "rewrite". The line you need looks like this:
>
> `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
>
> You need to take away the hash sign so it looks like this
>
> `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
>
> Now just save the file.

Reference: [WordPress Support - Answer by Samuel B](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalinks-on-localhost-yields-404)

And a warning:

> **REMEMBER:
>
>   NEVER EVER EDIT A CORE WORDPRESS FILE, IT'LL SIMPLY MAKE YOUR WP BUGGY.**

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use Custom Structure permalinks like this:
[www.example.com/blog/post/%post_id%/%postname%/](http://www.example.com/blog/post/%post_id%/%postname%/)

But just putting this `/blog/post/%post_id%/%postname%/` in the custom structure resulted in 404 error.

I was able to resolve this issue  by putting this in the custom structure field after reading some articles & trial n error:
`/index.php/blog/post/%post_id%/%postname%/` .

I use nginx.

Comment: Glad that worked, but that shouldn't be necessary I'd have thought? Your web server rewrite rules should remove the index.php (unless you want it there?)