# What is the best way to overwrite /wp-admin/ms-delete-site.php

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I have a multi-site network, and want to secure the  /wp-admin/ms-delete-site.php so that it does not execute. We want to manage site deletions from the command line only.

I have added a call to wp_die() at the top for now, but I would prefer to handle this in a plugin, and not make any changes to the WP core files.

What is the best way to implement this in a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to look at the hook [map_meta_cap](http://mannieschumpert.com/blog/wordpress-capabilities-magic-with-map_meta_cap/) and remove the user's capability to `delete_site`.  If you have a restricted set of users or context when you want to allow `delete_site` then you can allow the capability.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, [editing core is a no-no](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files).

Instead, you can do this.

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'wpse242553_no_delete_site_screen' );
function wpse242553_no_delete_site_screen() {
    // Check to see if we're using the CLI client. If so, bail out.
    if ( 'cli' == php_sapi_name() ) {
        return;
        // I'm not sure this is strictly necessary.
    }
    if ( 'ms-delete-site' == get_current_screen()->base ) {
        // You can add whatever message you like here,
        // or even use wp_safe_redirect() to go elsewhere.
        wp_die( 'Sorry, we only delete sites from the command line.' );
    }

}
```

Put it in a [Must Use plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) to have it applied on every site in your network.

### References

- [`current_screen` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/current_screen/)
- [`get_current_screen()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/)
- [`php_sapi_name()`](https://php.net/php_sapi_name) (I checked, and if you're using [`wp-cli`](https://wp-cli.org/), it returns `cli` as the SAPI name)