# Remove pipe in views admin page filter

Tags: filters, admin, views

I want to remove the pipes wich are beetween the links in views in the admin page ( For instance in the users page admin)  " All (2) | Cutomer (3) |  etc... " . How can I do ?
Somebody knows where they are added ?
Best regards

P.Coacolo

Comment: It appears there's not an easy way to filter that — the `|` character gets added directly in the code in [`wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L413), and it's [a very bad idea to hack core](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files). You could [open a ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) to suggest that it be made filterable.

Comment: I assume you can modify it with JS however you want

Answer (score 1):

ok best way is effectively to use js, added in custom plugin

```
$('.users-php ul.subsubsub li').each(function(index){
    $(this).html(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace('|', ' ');
    });
 });
```