# How to make changes to wordpress core files and make them resistant to wordpress updates?

Tags: core-modifications

I have my WordPress setup on IIS and it is rewritten. Because of that I found some probably bug in `wp_includes/canonical.php` file.

I think that when I update my WordPress that all my changes will disapear.

I can't wait for WordPress fix this (I don't even know if it is bug or how to report one) because that "bug" causes my homepage to go in redirect loop.

I made some change in `redirect_canonical` function in that file specificly this change:

```
function redirect_canonical( $requested_url = null, $do_redirect = true ) {
    ///some other code 
    if ( ! $requested_url && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) {
        // build the URL in the address bar
        $requested_url  = is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        //$requested_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] //I deleted this because my URL is rewritten 
        $asParts = parse_url( $sURL ); // PHP function
        $requested_url .= $asParts['host'] ;
        $requested_url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

How to make this change resistant to WordPress updates?

Comment: Why? Can you explain.

Comment: Don't. You shouldn't modify core files, especially when you don't know if it's a bug or not. Better to ask a question to see if that is a bug or not first.

Comment: You should never edit or make custom changes on WordPress core files. You can use the `redirect_canonical` filter and manipulate the final destination but you can make a big mess if you don't know what exactly you are doing: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/redirect_canonical/

Comment: I am new to wordpress development. Why downvote? If you don't know you can just skip, or explain why you made effort to click downvote. It is most easier way just to downvote. Explaining or answering however takes more time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there are more than one question in here, so let me address some of them...

### Why you should never modify WordPress core files?

In short words... Because it will be really hard to manage later on... If you modify the core, than you won't be able to update it - so what, when there's a security update? Will you be able to update your site quick enough? And are you sure that your modifications won't break anything?

Another reason is that you don't need to. Most of the times you just need to use some filters/actions and there is no need to make any modifications...

Here are some questions and links, that may be handy to get some deeper understanding of that subject:

- [Modifying WordPress core files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files)
- https://getflywheel.com/layout/wp-core/

### What if you really need to modify core files?

OK, so you really, really need to modify some core files and you completely understand consequences of such modifications. You modified those files and now want to make sure that WP won't overwrite these files during updates...

You can use `WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE` constant:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

Just set it in your `wp-config.php`.

You will still be able to do updates as admin, but that's easier to manage. Although you'll have to remember to merge your modifications with new WP version.

Another way would be to disable updates at all and manage them using GIT, etc.

### I found a bug. What next?

If you think this is a bug in WP, then you should report it. Here you can find some information on how to do this:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-bugs/

It's not so hard :)