# How exactly does Wordpress load themes from api.wordpress.org?

Tags: themes, http, wordpress.org

On a computer with Windows 7 there is a blocking all websites except those are specified in the file ***C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*** which serves as "DNS" like

```
123.456.789.123 example.com
```

and DNS in network adapter settings are switched to `127.0.0.1`

As I see in ***wp-admin/includes/theme.php***, free available WP themes in admin panel on pages *"Themes > Add new"* and *"Customize > Change > WordPress.org themes"* are loaded from the url api.wordpress.org. But this url is not mentioned in the hosts file.

So how can it be possible the themes are still loaded?

If I remove in ***wp-includes/class-http.php*** inside of the function `request()` the lines

```
$proxy = new WP_HTTP_Proxy();
if ( $proxy->is_enabled() && $proxy->send_through_proxy( $url ) ) {
    // ...
}
```

nothing changes and themes continue to load, so the proxy is not used.

How themes are loaded from api.wordpress.org bypassing DNS?

Comment: Do you mean the computer that has blocking set up is your own computer, or do you mean it's the actual server where your WordPress install is hosted?

Comment: Also, be aware that any changes you might make to `wp-includes/class-http.php` or any other core file will be overwritten on any WP update. [Don't Hack Core](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files), as they say.