# Sodium compat error

Tags: errors

Yesterday, looking into error_log file I've found this error:

[15-Oct-2019 08:23:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'CRYPTO_AEAD_XCHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_KEYBYTES' in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-includes/sodium_compat/lib/constants.php:22

Sodium compat cryptographic library has been added into WP since 5.2 version.

But I never seen this error... someone knows something about this issue?

Thanks for any help!

Regards

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `sodium` PHP extension installed & enabled if you're running PHP >7.2

Comment: George if you have a link to a 'How To' guide or some other details you should add them to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP 7.1 (and poss 7.0) you can comment out the related lines from autoload.php, they're not needed.

Comment: If you're suggesting editing an `autoload.php` file in the WordPress Core files, *don't*. See [this Q&A thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files) for a more nuanced explanation than the oft-quoted **don't hack core** aphorism.