# Warning: call_user_func_array() problem can anyone help with it?

Tags: plugins, wp-query

`Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'WP_Block_Supports' not found in /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_gd_image() in /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php:104 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-includes/media.php(3558): WP_Image_Editor_GD->load() #1 /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/inc/class-sb-instagram-gdpr-integrations.php(111): wp_get_image_editor('http://nischalk...') #2 /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/instagram-feed.php(550): SB_Instagram_GDPR_Integrations::gdpr_tests_successful(true) #3 /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): sbi_check_for_db_updates('') #4 /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-settings.php(568): do_action in /home/vol6_3/unaux.com/unaux_26684289/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php on line 104
There has been a critical error on this website.
```

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

**And when I follow that location and delete line 287 it says this site is not working right now. Here is the code of that location.**

```
// Avoid the array_slice() if possible.
                if ( 0 == $the_['accepted_args'] ) {
                    $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
                } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
            $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
                } else {
                    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
                }
            }
        } while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );
```

Comment: [is_gd_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_gd_image/) was added in WordPress 5.6. What version are you using? Have you added a plugin or theme that requires 5.6+?

Comment: Or you possibly have a bad upgrade that didn't overwrite wp-includes/media.php with the new version that defines is_gd_image.

Comment: "And when I follow that location and delete line 287 it says this site is not working right now." — [**Do not** arbitrarily delete code in WordPress Core.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files)

Comment: Line 287 isn't the problem anyway: that's the code that's trying to call a filter function that doesn't exist, whereas the problem is either 1) the code that set up that filter, i.e. look for an `add_filter` call somewhere whose second parameter is 'is_gd_image', or 2) something's wrong with your WordPress site (wrong version, bad upgrade) which means is_gd_image doesn't exist when it should.